# Thread 1: Program received signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, sigabrt

I'm just a newcomer in developing. I use xCode 4.6.3 and iOS 6 SDK.
While I run my project, it crashes and I can see that:"Program received signal SIGABRT".

Please, give me some solutions of that problem.

Maybe, I'm stupid, but I do it about month.

> [ISTableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x848b550'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1d73012 0x1526e7e 0x1dfe4bd 0x1d62bbc 0x1d6294e 0x2c58 0x158157 0x158747 0x15994b 0x16acb5 0x16bbeb 0x15d698 0x1893df9 0x1893ad0 0x1ce8bf5 0x1ce8962 0x1d19bb6 0x1d18f44 0x1d18e1b 0x15917a 0x15affc 0x2b7d 0x2aa5 0x1)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>   (gdb)

Comment: I've edited the irrelevant code out of your question. It was the implementation files for `ISTableViewController` which, as my answer suggests - does not implement the `topViewController` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Abizern says check your ISTableViewController whether it implements the topViewController. Probably you were trying to do a `[UIViewController topViewController]`.
You need to do `self.navigationController.topViewController`. self.navigationController can change depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained by the crash report here:

```
[ISTableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

You are sending the method `topViewController` to an object that does not implement the method.

Which means somewhere in your code (not in what you have shown here) you are sending a message to an object which is not what you think it is.